# Rails: collecting records from grandparent's attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-5

I've got a deep-nested relationship like so:

```
>> @document.template_variables.first.master.box.stack
=> #<Stack id: 6, name: "Contact information", direction: "down", x: 145.0, y: 145.0, template_id: 28, width: 55, page: 1, html_box: "column_right">
```

Master isn't *quite* a normal Rails relationship, and it's defined in `TemplateVariable` like so:

```
def master
  TemplateVariable.find(master_id) if master_id.present?
end
```

So it's kinda referring to another instance of itself, but as you can see from the log output on top it works fine.

My issue is that I need to get *all* `TemplateVariables` whose parent `Stack` matches the box name like so:

```
scope :by_box, -> (b) { where('box.stack.html_box' => b) }
```

But no matter what I try, even in the console, I can't get the query right.

```
>> @document.template_variables.where(master.box.stack.html_box != nil)
!! #<NameError: undefined local variable or method `master' for #<#<Class:0x007fd287cd9888>:0x007fd28bb11ee8>>
```

And the scope returns this error:

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid - PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  missing FROM-clause entry for table "box"
LINE 1: ...WHERE "template_variables"."document_id" = $1 AND "box"."sta...
```

Any help? What am I missing?

Comment: does `TemplateVariable` model `has_one :box` and `Box` model `has_one :stack`?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention that. Yeah, it's a `belongs_to` arrangement.

Comment: then I think this should work `scope :by_box, -> (b) { joins(box: :stack).where(stack: { html_box:  b }) }`

Comment: You've managed to change my error message. `html_box` is an attribute of the `stack`, not another relation. Here's the new error: `ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid - PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  missing FROM-clause entry for table "stack"`.

Comment: Sorry I made a mistake, it should be `:by_box, -> (b) { joins(box: :stack).where(stacks: { html_box: b }) }`

Comment: You just made my night. _Thank-you!_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I should create an answer here. Your scope raised error because you did not joins table `boxes` and `stacks` before your where clause `where('box.stack.html_box' => b)`. Rails would convert this to SQL query

```
SELECT "template_variables".* FROM "template_variables" WHERE "box"."stack.html_box" = ...
```

As you can see, this query has no idea about the where clause. which is `"box"` table? which is `"stack.html_box"` column?
So all you have to do is to join the `boxes` and `stacks` first, then the where clause would be `where(stacks: { html_box: b })` or `where('stacks.html_box' => b })` (`stacks` is plural because it is table name), which is convert to SQL query

```
SELECT "template_variables".* FROM "template_variables" INNER JOIN "boxes" ON "boxes"."id" = "template_variables"."box_id" INNER JOIN "stacks" ON "stacks"."id" = "boxes"."stack_id" WHERE "stacks"."html_box" = ...
```

and it would work well.
Another suggestion, you shoud define your `master` as a `belongs_to` association, like

```
belongs_to :master, class_name: 'TemplateVariable', foreign_key: :master_id
```

Hope this help.